# Why can't my python script import the function as: from functions import

Tags: python

the following python script should print the required Names

script read the `functions.py` that include the `get_names` function

```
more names.py

import os
import sys
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
python_files_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, 'python_files')
sys.path.append(python_files_dir)


from functions import *


#  name
Name = get_names()
print Name;
```

when we run the `names.py` , we get `get_names is not defined` , while actually `get_names` function is defined in `functions.py`

example when we run the `names.py`

```
python names.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "names.py", line 18, in <module>
    Name = get_names()
NameError: name 'get_names' is not defined
```

the `python_files/functions.py` script that include the function - `get_names`

```
more python_files/functions.py

def get_names(path='/tmp/folder_1'):

.
.
.
```

**I must to say that this happens only on one Linux machine , while the exactly script `names.py` , is working on other machines**

Comment: Is there another Module called functions? Maybe you could try this to get more information:  import functions; print (dir(functions))

Comment: functions  is represented the python_files/functions.py , and we have only one python_files/functions.py

Comment: @Judy Does `get_names` show up in the output sugested by *Easy_Israel*?

Comment: its not show any output from the bad machine

Comment: using `from my_module import *` is a really bad habit (and bad practice). You (or someone else) will spend hours debugging this some day...
Can you try using `from functions import get_names`?

Comment: From what you describe of your directories tree, you should be able to use relative import with `from python_files.functions import get_names`. Would be better than messing with PYTHON_PATH

Comment: now we get ImportError: cannot import name get_name

Comment: python_files/functions.py include many functions while one of them is get_names

Comment: So `get_names` may not be in your module. You mention *other machines*, is this module duplicated across several machines ?
If yes, please check this module is up to date and actually defines this function for the machine where you encounter the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204271/discussion-between-fabienp-and-judy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with it as though it were in a package, but it is not. It cannot find the file **functions.py** because it is within a directory. So either make that directory into a package by adding an `__init__.py` that way you'll be able to get it working like a package and  import simply with

`from python_file.function import get_name`

Or simply remove functions.py from the python_file directory and put it in the same directory with names.py, hence you should be able to import normally

```
from function import get_name
```

Instead of going through the unneeded long process of sys and os system path manipulation which could go wrong. Also avoid using 
`from module import *`
Because this is generally considered as bad practice more often than not and you might want to look into changing the module name from *functions.py* to something else